# Comparing Char in C in Do-While

Tags: c

So I am trying to do a do-while loop to end when the user enters a K or M character.

```
  char conversionChoice;
  do {
      printf("Enter K to convert from Kilometer to Miles\n"
             "Enter M to convert from Miles to Kilometer\n");
      scanf(" %c",&conversionChoice);

  }while (conversionChoice != "K" || conversionChoice != 'M');
```

What happens is the loop continues going, and if I enter KM then it will repeat the printf twice before asking for input. I'm new to C and wondering what I'm doing wrong for comparing chars

Comment: Replace `||` with `&&`. Obviously one of the `OR` operands will always be true.

Comment: `"K"` should be `'K'` - the first one is a string literal, but you want a character constant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
while (conversionChoice != "K" || conversionChoice != 'M')
```

to this:

```
while (conversionChoice != 'K' && conversionChoice != 'M')
```

where I put the character `K` in single quotes (and not double quotes), because it's a character, not a string - just like you correctly did already for `M`.

Also, I changed `||` to `&&` , since you want to continue looping while the variable is is not equal to M and not equal to K.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `||` with `&&`. Maybe one of the `OR` operands will be always true.

```
`"K"` should be `'K'`
```

Comment: So you copied the comments and added the wrong "maybe".

Comment: @EugeneSh. I didn’t copy it... it’ was my idea and I want to share the solution;)

Answer (score 0):

`||` stands for `OR` operator. Lets give an example, If you give the 'K' as an input, the OR operator will decide that the `conversionChoice != "K"` is equal to true, and `conversionChoice != 'M'` is equal to false.

In this case `OR` operator will return true because one of the expressions were true.

So you should use the `&&` which stands for `AND` operator.

```
do {....}
while (conversionChoice != "K" && conversionChoice != 'M');
```